# Background processes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, background-process, task-queue

What is a good aproach to handle background processes in a NodeJS application?

**Scenario**: After a user posts something to an app I want to crunch the data, request additional data from external resources, etc. All of this is quite time consuming, so I want it out of the req/res loop. Ideal would be to just have a queue of jobs where you can quickly dump a job on and a daemon or task runner will always take the oldest one and process it.

In RoR I would have done it with something like Delayed Job. What is the Node equivalent of this API?

Comment: The question is a software recommendation as it's phrased now, which will end up getting closed. If you were to replace the last sentence with "What is the NodeJS equivalent of this API?" it becomes more on-topic. I would like to see this answered rather than closed, since I need to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks, rephrased it.

Comment: Good suggestions below. There's also the `ChildProcess` API which might be useful. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/69349/ole-spaarmann - I would be interested in knowing what you finally chose and if you could provide a very simple example of how you integrated your decision with NodeJS - thanks !

Comment: @MLissCetrus I chose to learn Elixir and not use NodeJS anymore :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/69349/ole-spaarmann - ahh... easier ? harder ?  why ?

Comment: @MLissCetrus it solves a lot of hard problems like parallel processes in a very elegant way. It's just a damn sexy language.

Answer (score 139):

If you want something lightweight, that runs in the same process as the server, I highly recommend [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull). It has a simple API that allows for a fine grained control over your queues.

If you're familiar with Ruby's Resque, there is a node implementation called [Node-resque](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque)

Bull and Node-resque are all backed by [Redis](http://redis.io/), which is ubiquitous among Node.js worker queues. They would be able to do what RoR's DelayedJob does, it's matter of specific features that you want, and your API preferences.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but mentioning the ChildProcess API and [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) module could make it great. ;)

Comment: @ssube I disagree with you. Unless you mean creating a fork that looks at a queue to run some command you are right. +1 from me. Child_process is what I am using and my problem is that I could open up a huge set of processes, but if I had a way to manage the tasks to be run in a queue, then I would be happy that CP is a good solution. This can be done, but the point is to not do all the work yourself, but to reuse code that is battle tested (in this case something like Kue that does all the magic you need and allow api integrations).

Comment: Does Bull work with PM2 clustering? Or do you need to create your own clusters manually, as shown in their documentation?

Comment: @Yuri Zarubin  your answer should be edited to mention that Kue is now deprecated.

Answer (score 42):

Background jobs are not directly related to your web service work, so they should not be in the same process.  As you scale up, the memory usage of the background jobs will impact the web service performance.  But you can put them in the same code repository if you want, whatever makes more sense.

One good choice for messaging between the two processes would be [redis](http://redis.io/commands#pubsub), if dropping a message every now and then is OK.  If you want "no message left behind" you'll need a more heavyweight broker like [Rabbit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).  Your web service process can publish and your background job process can subscribe.

It is not necessary for the two processes to be co-hosted, they can be on separate VMs, Docker containers, whatever you use.  This allows you to scale out without much trouble.

Comment: Really the only answer that has mentioned Rabbit? This is the enterprise answer. +1

Comment: @wberry Would your answer change taking Nodejs worker threads into consideration?

Comment: I haven't worked with Node for a few years now.  But this new threading system seems counter to the original intent of the language.  My instinct is to avoid using this module except in those narrow cases it was meant for - CPU intensive computations that are awkward to implement with `setImmediate` calls.

Comment: The major concerns with combining housekeeping and transactional code in the same process are memory and I/O.  If the housekeeping code turns into a hog it can impact the traffic.  Using the Worker package would remove the need of a broker but expose you to these risks.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using MongoDB, I recommend [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda).  That way, separate Redis instances aren't running and features such as scheduling, queuing, and Web UI are all present.  [Agenda UI](https://github.com/moudy/agenda-ui) is optional and can be run separately of course.

Would also recommend setting up a loosely coupled abstraction between your application logic and the queuing / scheduling system so the entire background processing system can be swapped out if needed.  In other words, keep as much application / processing logic away from your Agenda job definitions in order to keep them lightweight.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest using [Redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) for scheduling jobs. It has plenty of different data structures, you can always pick one that suits better to your use case.

You mentioned RoR and DJ, so I assume you're familiar with sidekiq. You can use [node-sidekiq](https://github.com/loopj/node-sidekiq) for job scheduling if you want to, but its suboptimal imo, since it's main purpose is to integrate nodejs with RoR.

For worker daemonising I'd recommend using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). It's widely used and actively-maintained. It solves a lot of problems (e.g. deployment, monitoring, clustering) so make sure it won't be an overkill for you.

Answer (score 4):

I tried [bee-queue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) & [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and chose bull in the end. 
I first chose bee-queue b/c it is quite simple, their examples are easy to understand, while bull's examples are bit complicated. bee's wiki [Bee Queue's Origin](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue/wiki/Origin) also resonates with me. But the problem with bee is <1> their issue resolution time is quite slow, their latest update was 10 months ago. <2> I can't find an easy way to pause/cancel job.

Bull, on the other hand, frequently updates their codes, response to issues. [Node.js job queue evaluation](https://bl.ocks.org/twolfson/a8e5bca55ad825ff49305e457fbf46ca) said bull's weakness is "slow issues resolution time", but my experience is the opposite!

But anyway their api is similar so it is quite easy to switch from one to another.

Answer (score -8):

I suggest to use a proper Node.js framework to build you app.

I think that the most powerful and easy to use is [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/).

It's a MVC framework so if you are used to develop in ROR, you will find it very very easy!

If you use it, It's already present a powerful (in javascript terms) job manager.

```
new sails.cronJobs('0 01 01 * * 0', function () {
   sails.log.warn("START ListJob");
}, null, true, "Europe/Dublin");
```

If you need more info not hesitate to contact me!

Comment: I am looking for a background process manager for Node. By definition this should be seperate from your web app. And it shouldn't matter if you use Sails, Express, Hapi or whatever you like.

Comment: Ok you can try Bull or Webworker-Threads... good luck whit Node.js :)

Comment: It looks like sails.js is pretty big and does much more than cronJobs. I found node-cron (https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) which I bet is what sails.js uses.

Comment: why everyone in nodejs or js suggesting package.. is no one doing in vanilla js..