# Can I use child process or cluster to do custom function calls in node?

Tags: node.js

I have a node program that does a lot of heavy *synchronous* work. The work that needs to be done could easily be split into several parts. I would like to utilize all processor cores on my machine for this. Is this possible?

Form the docs on [child processes](https://iojs.org/api/child_process.html) and [clusters](https://iojs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) I see no obvious solution. Child processes seems to be focused on running external programs and clusters only work for incoming http connections (or have I misunderstood that?).

I have a simple function `var output = fn(input)` and would just like to run it several times, spread all the calls across the cores on my machine and provide the result in a callback. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, child processes and clusters are the way to do that. There are a couple of ways of implementing a solution to your problem.

1. Your server creates a queue and manages that queue. Whenever you need to call your function, you will drop it into the queue. You will then process the queue N items at a time, where N equals the number of your cores. When you start processing, you will spawn a child process, probably either using `spawn` or `exec`, with the argument being another standalone Node.js script, along with any additional parameters (it's just a command line call, basically). Inside that script you will do your work, and emit the result back to the server. The worker is then freed up.
2. You can create a dedicated server with cluster, where all it will do is run your function. With the `cluster` module, you can (once again) create N number of other workers, and delegate work to these wokers.

Now this may seem like a lot of work, and it is. And for that reason you should use an existing library as this is a, for the most part, a solve problem at this point. I really like redis-based queues, so if you're interested in that see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009340/background-processes-in-node-js/31009563#31009563) for some queue recommendations.

Comment: Ok so basically what you are saying is that my assumptions about child processes and clusters are correct and if I want to just execute a function to do this I need to put it in a standalone script that I or make a server that just performs the function call and get the response through a local http request?

Comment: That's right, node.js is a single threaded event loop, and javascript has no threading library. If you want to use more cores, you need additional loops, hence additional processes via child processes.

Comment: I am aware of the event loop. I just find it strange that when cluster capabilities are added to node, they are strictly tied to the http server.

Comment: They aren't tied to the http server. The cluster module just spawns processes, it has no context of http. I used the word "server" in the general sense.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood the cluster documentation. Will make another deep dive into it.

Comment: Don't know why this has been accepted as a valid answer. I'm struggling with the same thing. I need to run a synchronous process thousands of times and am trying to use the clustering method, but all examples I can find are with the http server and not running a function directly